# CSS Help adding hosted icon fonts with css

Tags: css, fonts, icons

In my css a "~" is placed before and after a title. like this. I would like have a rocket icon instead.

```css
.menu-title:after, 
    .menu-title:before {
        content: "~"
    }
```

Im wondering how a hosted Icon could be used without putting in a Span around the Titles because  Titles  are dynamically added in the php of a Wordpress theme.

```html
<!-- Single Element -->
<span class="zocial-dribbble"></span>
```

but can it be added like this:

```css
.menu-title:after, 
    .menu-title:before {
        content: "<span class="entypo-rocket active"></span>"
    }
```

well so far the answer is no, but maybe some has a clever idea!

Comment: What do you mean by "hosted icon"?

Comment: And you obviously have a syntax error here: `content: "class="zocial-dribbble""`... look at the quoting chars!

Comment: Just like Hosted Fonts from Google but they have Icons instead: http://weloveiconfonts.com

Comment: Ok, sure that is possible. What I don't understand in your code: why do you try to add a `class` inside your content line in the css rule? Why not the icon/character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I got you right...

Maybe this is what you are looking for: [example on fiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/Xeuu4/)

Markup:

```
<a class="char">Some title</a>
<br>
<a class="icon">Some title</a>
<br>
<a class="zocial">Some title</a>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=zocial);
a { 
    font-size: 120px; 
    text-align: baseline; 
}
.char:before, .char:after { 
    margin: 20px;
    content:"~"; 
}
.icon:before, .icon:after { 
    content: url("http://www.gigadictionary.org/image-upload/1087.gif"); 
}
.zocial:before, .zocial:after { 
    font-family: 'zocial', sans-serif;
    content: "b";
}
```

Comment: Using hosted icons is not the problem, maybe I should re ask my question- CSS Help can CSS be used to write code on the fly?

Comment: Ah, ok... Simple answer to _that_ question: not that I am aware of.